# Define a standalone patch as YAML

Tags: kubernetes, fluxcd

I have a need to define a standalone patch as YAML.

More specifically, I want to do the following:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "registry-my-registry"}]}'
```

The catch is I can't use `kubectl patch`. I'm using a GitOps workflow with flux, and that resource I want to patch is a default resource created outside of flux.

In other terms, I need to do the same thing as the command above but with `kubectl apply` only:

```
kubectl apply patch.yaml
```

I wasn't able to figure out if you can define such a patch.

**The key bit is that I can't predict the name of the default secret token on a new cluster (as the name is random, i.e. `default-token-uudge`)**

Comment: Is the solution provided below what you were looking for?

Comment: @willrof unfortunately not

Comment: Have you checked the solution I provided? Tell me if that works for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

> - Fields set and deleted from Resource Config are merged into Resources by `Kubectl apply`:
> - If a Resource already exists, Apply updates the Resources by merging the
>   local Resource Config into the remote Resources
> - Fields removed from the Resource Config will be deleted from the remote Resource

You can learn more about [Kubernetes Field Merge Semantics](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/app_management/field_merge_semantics.html).

- If your limitation is not knowing the secret `default-token-xxxxx` name, no problem, just keep that field out of your yaml.
- As long as the yaml has enough fields to identify the target resource (name, kind, namespace) it will add/edit the fields you set.
- I created a cluster (minikube in this example, but it could be any) and retrieved the current default serviceAccount:

```
$ kubectl get serviceaccount default -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-01T14:51:38Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "330"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/default
  uid: a9e5ff4a-8bfb-466f-8873-58c2172a5d11
secrets:
- name: default-token-j6zx2
```

- Then, we create a yaml file with the content's that we want to add:

```
$ cat add-image-pull-secrets.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
imagePullSecrets:
 - name: registry-my-registry
```

- Now we apply and verify:

```
$ kubectl apply -f add-image-pull-secrets.yaml 
serviceaccount/default configured

$ kubectl get serviceaccount default -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: registry-my-registry
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"registry-my-registry2"}],"kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"default","namespace":"default"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-07-01T14:51:38Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2382"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/default
  uid: a9e5ff4a-8bfb-466f-8873-58c2172a5d11
secrets:
- name: default-token-j6zx2
```

As you can see, the ImagePullPolicy was added to the resource.

I hope it fits your needs. If you have any further questions let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let say, your service account YAML looks like bellow:

```sh
$ kubectl get sa demo -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: demo
  namespace: default
secrets:
 - name: default-token-uudge
```

Now, you want to add or change the `imagePullSecrets` for that service account. To do so, edit the YAML file and add `imagePullSecrets`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: demo
  namespace: default
secrets:
 - name: default-token-uudge
imagePullSecrets:
 - name: myregistrykey
```

And finally, apply the changes:

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f service-account.yaml
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. I can't predict what the name of the default token on a new cluster as the last five characters are random. I need this to work on any new cluster that is spun up.